# Identity Server 4 integrating with IBM Security Access Manager - CallbackPath

Tags: authentication, identityserver4

I would like to know which uri I should set up to integrate our Idsrv4 with Ibm SAM provider.  But I don't know which uri I should set up for `CallbackPath`

We have already integrated with external Idsv, Google without any problem.  But we are currently stuck at the integration with Ibm server because we don't know how to set up the `CallbackPath`

This is my code in Startup.cs

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("ibmsam", "Ibm Sam", options =>
                        {
                            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                            options.Authority = "https://IbmUrl";
                            options.ClientId = "myClientId";
                            options.ClientSecret = "mySecret";
                            options.ResponseType = "id_token";
                            options.SaveTokens = true;

                            options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
                            options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email);

                            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-idsrv"; // <<--- what should I set here?
                        });
```

As far as I know, there are separate uris for different provider:

- signin-google - Google
- signin-idsrv - Another Identity Server
- signin-aad - Azure Ad

So, I am wondering, whether there is already a predefined uri to integrate with ibm server (Eg. signin-ibmsam, etc...).  Where can I see how the list of signin-xxx and how these things work?

I tried to find it in IdentityServer4 github sourcecode.  But I couldn't find anywhere how these urls/paths are defined and how they handle the callback.

Could you please help me where I can find the sourcecodes for these paths?

Should we create a new path (signin-ibmsam) and implement our own `CallbackPath` and handle the callback, get tokens, user info, etc...?

Could you please suggest me how can I achieve it?

**UPDATED With Answer**
As Tore answered, we can provide any url as long as the same url is registered in the server.

For my case, I use like the following:

```
options.CallbackPath = "/signin-ibm";
```

and I gave the full urls (Eg. https://test.ttcg.com/signin-ibm, https://www.ttcg.com/signin-ibm) to another team who register these urls in the OAuth Provider.  As long as those two matches in two systems, it's going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback path for the AddOpenIdConnect handler is by default /signin-oidc, as you can find in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs) of the OpenIdConnectOptions class. Your IBM server needs to redirect back to this fixed url. If you need to customize it you can always set it using:

```
options.CallbackPath = "/my-callback-path";
```